# User input repeatedly error

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple program that initializes a list for the grades to be entered by the user and adds grades to the grade list. Also I want my user to be able to repeatedly prompt grades to the list until the user enters a blank grade. My problem is my code does not stop when a blank input is placed by the user.

Here is my initial code:

```
grade_list=[]
valid_input=True
while valid_input:
    grade= input ("Enter your grade:")
    grade_list.append(grade)
else:
   valid_input= false
   print(grade_list)
```

Comment: The code you have posted here does not run. Please post your actual code.

Comment: In your code `valid_input` has 3 different names. (Only on of which is valid)

Comment: So my code does not stop prompting user for grade even after entering a blank input.  I think it is in my else statement but where or how do I state that so it will terminate adding grades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:
(1) You never change the value of valid_input: you cannot get to the "else" branch.
(2) You don't do anything in the "true" branch to check the input.

You can get rid of the variable and simplify the loop: just grab the first input before the loop, and then control the loop by directly checking the input.  This is the "old-school" way to run a top-checking loop.

```
grade_list = []
grade = input ("Enter your grade:")

while grade:
    grade = input ("Enter your grade:")
    grade_list.append(grade)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grade_list = []
while True:
    grade = input('Enter your grade: ')
    if not grade:
        break
    grade_list.append(grade)
print(grade_list)
```

Comment: As a rule, just implementing the OP's code without explaining what you've changed or why isn't terribly helpful.